# Is there any website/software that secures your payment when working with remote clients?

Tags: contracts, freelance-websites, payment-terms, payments, freelance

Apart from job marketplaces, Is there any software or website that secures your payment when working with remote clients and manages the payment between you and your client?

Comment: You are seeking an [Escrow provider](https://www.google.com/search?q=escrow+providers&oq=escrow+provider&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0i512j0i22i30l5j0i390l2.2617j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Merely searching the interest will turn up many.

Comment: I think blockchain smart contracts can be leveraged to do that, but there are different ways, depends on the overarching system. I personally think blockchain could be more modern and even convenient. There is one online Escrow tool that looks alright:

Comment: https://www.escrow.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can get payment through https://www.deal.com
This is the most safe way to make payment because it pends 15 days for verification, passport or id card verification.

Comment: You probably mean Deel, not Deal?

Answer (score 0):

As far As I know and mostly use Upwork Direct Contract, Although It deducts some amount it's a fast and secure method.

Answer (score -1):

There are several options for securely handling payments when working with remote clients. Here are a few options:

**Escrow services:** These are third-party platforms that hold onto funds until the work is completed to the satisfaction of both parties. Examples include Escrow.com and SafePay.

**Payment processors:** Services like PayPal, Stripe, and Square allow you to securely process payments online.

**Online invoicing platforms:** Platforms like FreshBooks and QuickBooks allow you to create and send invoices to clients, and also offer secure payment processing options.

**Project management software:** Some project management tools, such as Asana and Trello, offer integrations with payment processors and allow you to track payments as part of your project workflow.

It's always a good idea to carefully research and compare the features and fees of different platforms before choosing one to use.